# EntityFramework NotMapped but return results

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This might sound odd, but I have an entity:

```
public class Center : Archive
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string ExternalId { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(150)] public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)] public string Description { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string Address1 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string Address2 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string Address3 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string Address4 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(10)] public string PostCode { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)] public string CollectionPointContact { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string CollectionPointTelephone { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string CollectionPointFax { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)] public string CollectionPointEmail { get; set; }

    [NotMapped] public int Due { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] public int Today { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] public int Expected { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] public int Planned { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public IList<Collection> Collections { get; set; }
}
```

When listing, editing, creating, etc. The `[NotMapped]` properties should not be mapped in the database. 
But, I have a stored procedure that populates these properties:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ListCentersByCompany]
    @CompanyId [int]
AS
BEGIN
    select ce.*,
           SUM(CASE WHEN co.PlannedCollectionDate < CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Due,
           SUM(CASE WHEN co.PlannedCollectionDate = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Today,
           SUM(CASE WHEN co.PlannedCollectionDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Expected,
           SUM(CASE WHEN co.PlannedCollectionDate > DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Planned
    from Centers ce join
         Collections co
         on ce.Id = co.CenterId
    WHERE ce.CompanyId = @CompanyId
    group by 
        ce.Id,
        ce.ExternalId,
        ce.Name,
        ce.Description,
        ce.Address1,
        ce.Address2,
        ce.Address3,
        ce.Address4,
        ce.PostCode,
        ce.CollectionPointContact,
        ce.CollectionPointEmail,
        ce.CollectionPointFax,
        ce.CollectionPointTelephone,
        ce.CompanyId,
        ce.CreatedById,
        ce.ModifiedById,
        ce.DateCreated,
        ce.DateModified
END
```

EntityFramework knows not to map them, but when I use my SPROC I would like them to be mapped.
Is that possible? I realise, I could just create a new model and use that instead but I want to know if there is something easier?

Comment: If you absolutely want to use the same model, you could try removing the `NotMapped` attributes and instead overriding `OnModelBuilding` in your `DbContext` to use the fluent configuration to tell EF that those properties are not mapped. (not 100% sure it would work though)

Comment: doesn't that do the same as NotMapped?

Comment: @ESG No, `[NotMapped]` and ignoring in the fluent mapping API are equivalent.

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought

Comment: How do you  run the sproc, and which EF version is this?

Comment: 6.2 and I have a method that looks like this `_context.Database.SqlQuery<T>($"exec {storedProcedureName}").ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of `Database.SqlQuery`, with or without entity types, is [documented extensively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0):

> Creates a raw SQL query that will return elements of the given type. The type can be any type that has properties that match the names of the columns returned from the query, or can be a simple primitive type. The type does not have to be an entity type. The results of this query are never tracked by the context even if the type of object returned is an entity type.

*Yet*, the somewhat quirky behavior with non-mapped properties isn't mentioned. Which is that running...

```
_context.Database.SqlQuery<T>($"exec {storedProcedureName}")
```

...doesn't populate not-mapped properties when `T` is a mapped entity type. It does when any other type is used that contains the matching properties. I think that's a bit weird and I even suspect it's unintended behavior.

So you can't use `Center` as the receiving type, but you can use an non-mapped type directly inheriting from `Center`.